# Java design: Adding common functionality to classes that extend the same base class, without modifying base class

Tags: java, polymorphism, abstract

I'm trying to figure out how to best solve this problem in a project I'm working on. I'll give an analogy of the problem:

There is a class, **Car**. Out of **Car**, I create 3 classes that extend it:

- **Limo** extends **Car**
- **Truck** extends **Car**
- **Bus** extends **Car**

Now, say I realize that someone forgot to include a **getSpeed()** method to the Car class, and I need to add it. But, *I cannot modify the Car class in any way, and the 3 classes must extend Car.* How can I best add a common functionality to these 3 classes without having to copy paste code back and forth? The implementation for the **getSpeed()** method is the same for each class, so I would like something like an abstract class, but still be able to keep the classes as extending Car.

This is an example of my only way around it so far but I'm curious if there's a better way:

```
public class Limo extends Car {
    CarSpeed cs;
    public Limo() {
        cs = new CarSpeed(this);
    }
}
```

and have the **CarSpeed** class contain the actual **getSpeed()** method.

Is there a cleaner way to do this that I'm not aware of? I'm also only able to work in Java 7, so I don't think I can use the default keyword (not that I've read up on it enough to know if it's applicable to this situation :( )

Comment: May I ask why you can't add getSpeed() to Car? The whole point of inheritance is to adopt certain features of the parent/base class.

Comment: It's part of a jar file that I'm not able to conveniently recompile :(

Comment: Yikes. Hmmm.... so basically your importing the library then correct?

Comment: Right, basically I can see the source of "Car" but can't use a modified version without a lot of trouble.

Comment: Ok, i hate to say it and i know you don't want to copy/paste but maybe using an interface wouldn't be such a bad solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible ways to accomplish this:

1. Add `getSpeed()` to the Car class so that the other classes can inherit this method. This is probably the best way since it follows OOP.
2. Create an interface and add `getSpeed()` to it. The only thing is that other classes like Limo, Truck, and Bus will have to create the body of `getSpeed()` when you implement the interface.